Power Query Extract Value from Rows
I have this powerquery that I want to extract the values highlighted in Row 5 to another column. I can easily use
Record.Field(#"Added Custom"{4},"Column17")

But the problem I have is that this value can appear anywhere from column 12 to column 20 but still on Row 5.
How can I find it within that row to extract it.
Thank you.


To find the only non-null value in row 5 between columns 12 and 20, use this, replacing the word Source with your #"Prior Step Name" likely #"Added Custom"
Value = List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source),11,9)){4})){0}

Alternate version that looks for first text containing { in row 5 between columns 12 and 20
Value = List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source),11,9)){4})), each if Text.Contains(_,"{") then _ else null)){0}

version 2 Try this.... add column ... custom column that has fomula
= try List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(List.Range(Record.FieldValues(_),11,9)), each if Text.Contains(_,"{") then _ else null){0} otherwise null

then right click column and fill down, then right click and fill up

Some of the values in the rows are not null, but the string that I want to extract all come in the format that looks like this 27^{th} February 2023, 2^{nd} June 2023 etc. The unique thing about the value is that they all have the curly bracket "{"

Thank you so much. The alternate solution worked great, but I noticed that when I added a line below to copy the value into another column it does work, but when the code reaches another date value, it still copies the first date. I will like the date to be changing as it encounters new dates. Maybe I did not write the code below properly:
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "MyDate", each Value )

You are correct. The issue here is that I am reading from multiple PDF files. For a single PDF file the value is in row 5. Now when I bring in a folder to read the files, it still picks from row 5. Maybe I would have re-phrased the question to read from all the rows and extract values that have "{" to another row

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you so much, your ideas helped me in solving the problem. I modified your solution and it is now working.
